# Sharpness of starlight

Tags: cosmology, astronomy

I am interested in argument that the observed lack of blurriness in starlight refutes the "tired light" theories.  I have not been able to find this argument expanded in detail.

There are two ways that I can think of that we observe the lack of blurriness:

1. In absorption spectra, the lines are sharp, indicating a sharpness in light frequency.
2. In the apparent size of a distant object: if the mechanism that caused the light to become tired was the result of some collision, then the direction of travel of the photons would presumably deviate slightly making the apparent size larger and the object appear blurry.

Can upper limits be placed on any blurriness from experimental data in both cases? What would it mean if there is a difference between the two, for instance if we could detect a small blurriness in direction, but none in frequency?

Comment: Did you look at the Wikipedia article? It has plenty of references, including Zwicky's paper. Interestingly, Zwicky himself was already able to rule out a number of physical effects that could lead to "tired light". As for the latest "limits", I think the most interesting limit of this kind is being set for Planck scale fluctuations. Using observations of the coherent character of light from distant galaxies http://iopscience.iop.org/1538-4357/585/2/L77/pdf/1538-4357_585_2_L77.pdf sets a limit on naive models of Planck scale physics, far below the "tired light" effect.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the Wikipedia article.  Thanks for the reference.  That seems to demonstrate lack of blurriness in the _speed_ of light.

Comment: It clearly shows that the question has great relevance, even today, although for different reasons than in the original proposal. I think one should add, that light has a self-interaction, if we are willing to believe the standard model, and it clearly interacts with charged particles in the interstellar medium. For visible light the first effect can be neglected, however, if we were to apply it to a (now ruled out) steady-state model, where one should be able to "see forever" in an infinite universe, then it would make that universe foggy, albeit only for extremely long distances.

Comment: By saying light has a self-interaction, is this along the lines of saying that two photons travelling on parallel paths over long distances can, if close enough, become "focused" (whatever that means)?

Comment: It means that quantum electrodynamics predicts a self-interaction of photons (which has not been tested experimentally, yet, but will be within the next decade, or so). The result for low energy photons would be scattering, but, like I said, it doesn't play a role at this time for a physically realistic universe.

Comment: @CuriousOne did two photon scattering ever pan out? When would you expect it to be conclusively proven? I ask because I have a suspicion that QED is wrong